# Getting to convergance too early in GA

Tags: java, selection, genetic-algorithm

I am currently working on Genetic Algorithm to solve the problem of groups allocation (Assigning students to balanced groups as much as possible )..I have implemented the whole algorithm but I don’t know if it produces results in high quality or not. I think I get to convergence too early as it keeps the same solution (with no improvement) starting from the 10th generation or so.

I have used 2-tournmenat selection and ordered crossover. I have tried to set different population size, tournament size and mutation rate but it did not help!
Where is the problem? It’s been a week and I am stuck in the same progress.

Any suggestion?

Comment: You haven't provided any useful information or really asked an answerable question.  Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask].

Comment: Could you provide some more details on exactly how big your population size, tournament size and mutation rates and gene lengths are? It's a little hard to specifically target the problem without some finer grained details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be converging quickly on a local maxima; this is an inherent problem in genetic algorithms. You can usually detect such a state by long generational periods with no progress.

If this is the case, probably the easiest solution is to save off the stuck population and create a new one. Hopefully this one will get stuck at the global maxima, or at least a different local maxima. Then you can then compare the two populations and keep the one with the better solution. It's also sometimes possible, depending on how well the genes can be correlated, to breed the two populations together in an attempt to find an even better solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer , I think my algorithm stucked with a local optimal solution .
I will try your suggestions and let you know if it works ..

Answer (score 2):

In general if your GA is converging too quickly there are a couple things you need to look at:

- Is your mutation/crossover rate set appropriately? If this is too low your population stagnates rather quickly.
- Is your performance metric sensible? If the metric is poorly calibrated you end up giving too high an advantage to one group that will quickly dominate the gene pool.
- Are you using enough random data? If you're dealing with a very small solution space it probably doesn't make sense to use a GA, and if you do you'll end up converging very quickly.
- Is your implementation actually correct? It's really easy to introduce some subtle logic error that are very difficult to find. I would suggest stepping through a generation with the debugger and making sure key points act like you assume they do.

That said, ten generations isn't totally unreasonable. I would suggest making sure that something is actually wrong with your performance before asserting that something is wrong with your GA.

Comment: Thank you very much for your useful explanation ,, you opened my mind to think out of the box ..
Actually I am using too small set of data (only 9 students ) and allocate them to 3 groups only .I did that as it is the first time that I am dealing with GA and I preferred to start  with manageable data ..
I have read a lot of papers that present this problem and tried to implement it in the way they suggested so I don’t know if there is guideline to choose specific numbers for parameters .